# How to select an element in jquery autocomplete list using an external button

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have come across a scenario in which I have an autocomplete input box (jquery autocomplete). When user types in something, we get a suggestion list. But in my req, I have to hide that list and show a different list by selecting element from that list. Lets say original list is something like this

```
<ul>
<li><a>first element</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a>second element</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hide above ul list and show it in div structure by fetching element from this list

```
<div><div>first element</div></div>
<div><div>second element</div></div>
```

Now the problem comes when user clicks on div to select the value. What I did is trigger the click event of corresponding anchor tag, but it always select the first element in ul list and not the one on which I triggered the click event. On analysis I found that autocomplete selects the one which is hovered (internally it gets the element from this.select). IS there a solution by which I can achieve this ?

Reason I need to display in div structure is because I need to show autocomplete list in pagination fashion.

To replicate the scenario, lets say I want to select an element from list by clicking the button "Click to select"

http://jsfiddle.net/s24101984/LAT32/62/

Comment: show what have you tried ? jQuery

Comment: I tried something like this

`code`    
    $('#select').click(function(){
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete li:nth-child(2) a').trigger('click');    
    });
`code`